# How to sort and delete specific files?

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

(I didn't realize long posts were frowned upon)

My program reads a directory of files that looks similar to the following:

```
BkUpSalesReportJan2011(txt).zip
BkUpSalesReportJan2011(pdf).zip
BkUpSalesReportJan2011(doc).zip
BkUpSalesReportFeb2011(txt).zip
BkUpSalesReportMar2011(doc).zip
BkUpSalesReportMar2011(pdf).zip
Goes on for a few hundred more files...
```

I want to save only one copy of each report based on file type (in order of priority). I want to keep PDFs and delete all the duplicates. If there were no PDFs then keep DOCs and lastly keep the TXTs.

What is the best way to implement the sorting and deleting using Visual C# and windows forms?

Comment: **TL;DR**. Do you have a concrete question in there or are you asking for general guidance? The former is on-topic while the latter most likely is off-topic.

Comment: Well, instead of explaining why the Big Bang happened, just post along the following guide: Error, code leading to error, question at hand. This business of explaining everything makes me want to skip the whole thing.

Comment: Your question consists of valid and specific question and rest 75% of text is completely irrelevant and is not really appreciated here (it is not blog or something). Please extract meaningful question and remove the rest.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: The best way to understand your questions is to TRY it and see the advantages and disadvantages of that approach.  Learn to profile and use that to guide your refactoring and rewrites.

Comment: Edit this post, I beg of you. Describe the problem you have in one paragraph. I'm still not sure that the directories and file deletion is your goal here.

Comment: Your problem seems to be stated concisely now, but you have not described what you have tried.

Comment: This question might now be 'acceptable' but it doesn't seem to reflect in any way the asker's original concern, namely how does one decide on a programming approach and plan a solution when faced with an open-ended real-world problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124023/how-can-i-learn-to-plan-and-reason-about-solutions-to-non-trivial-programming-pr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Regex to parse the file names for the data and Linq to get the Duplicates or Distinct records.

POCO:

```
public class FileData
{
    public string Original { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Weight { get { return GetWeight(Type); } }

    private static int GetWeight(string option)
    {
        // This will put the files in order by pdf, doc, txt, etc
        switch(option)
        {
            case "pdf":
                return 0;
            case "doc":
                return 1;
            case "txt":
                return 2;
            default:
                return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

You will need a weight function since the default `OrderBy` will work alphabetically. This way you can specify which files have more significance.

Code:

```
// you can substitute this with Directory.GetFiles
// e.g. var files = Directory.GetFiles("Path/To/Files");
var files = new []
{
    "BkUpSalesReportJan2011(txt).zip",
    "BkUpSalesReportJan2011(pdf).zip",
    "BkUpSalesReportJan2011(doc).zip",
    "BkUpSalesReportFeb2011(txt).zip",
    "BkUpSalesReportMar2011(doc).zip",
    "BkUpSalesReportMar2011(pdf).zip"
};

var pattern = @"(?<FileName>.+)\((?<FileType>\w+)\)\.zip";
// (?<FileName>.+) Match the first part in a named group
// \( Match the first open parenthesis
// (?<FileType>\w+) Match the txt/pdf/doc/whatever in a named group
// \) Match the closing parenthesis
// \.zip Match a period followed by the zip

var matchedFiles = files.Select(f => Regex.Match(f, pattern))
                        .Where(m => m.Success)
                        .Select(f =>
                            new FileData
                                {
                                    Type = f.Groups["FileType"].Value,
                                    Name = f.Groups["FileName"].Value,
                                    Original = f.Value
                                }
                               ).ToList();

// Group all the files by the name e.g. BkUpSalesReportJan2011
// Transform the group into order and take the first record
// Take the original file name to get the originals
var distinct = matchedFiles.GroupBy(f => f.Name)
                           .Select(g => g.OrderBy(f => f.Weight).First())
                           .Select(f => f.Original);

// Group all the files by the name e.g. BkUpSalesReportJan2011
// Transform the group into order and skip the first record
// Since the records are still in a nested IEnumerable we need to flatten it
// Take the original file name to get the duplicates
var duplicates = matchedFiles.GroupBy(f => f.Name)
                             .Select(g => g.OrderBy(f => f.Weight).Skip(1))
                             .SelectMany(g => g)
                             .Select(f => f.Original);
```

See also:

[`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx)